# keras occasional crashing during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tf.keras

My keras code crashes occasionally during training (~20% of the time):

```
988/992 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0764 - accuracy: 0.9739 
    992/992 [==============================] - 15s 15ms/step - loss: 0.0763 - accuracy: 0.9739 - val_loss: 0.0990 - val_accuracy: 0.9623
    Epoch 46/500
    934/992 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0749 - accuracy: 0.9741Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
      File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
      File "/Users/me/Documents/code/model_creator.py", line 77, in <module>
        main()
      File "/Users/me/Documents/code/model_creator.py", line 58, in proc
        model.train_model()
      File "/Users/me/Documents/code/model_creator.py", line 121, in train_model
        hist = model.fit(data,
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 53, in quick_execute
        tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:
    Detected
   at node model/normalization/truediv defined at .node model/normalization/truediv defined at (most recent):
      File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
      File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
      File "/Users/me/Documents/code/model_creator.py", line 77, in <module>
      File "/Users/me/Documents/code/model_creator.py", line 58, in proc
      File "/Users/me/Documents/code/obj/base_model_object.py", line 121, in train_model
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1807, in fit
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1401, in train_function
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1384, in step_function
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1373, in run_step
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1150, in train_step
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 590, in __call__
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/base_layer.py", line 1149, in __call__
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/functional.py", line 515, in call
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/functional.py", line 672, in _run_internal_graph
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/base_layer.py", line 1149, in __call__
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 96, in error_handler
      File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/layers/preprocessing/normalization.py", line 362, in call
    Incompatible shapes: [32,10,14] vs. [0]
         [[{{node model/normalization/truediv}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_20451]
```

I am training it each time with the same data and all same parameters, except the number of epochs - (10, 25, 50, 100, 500).

The epoch step it crashes on varies, but it crashes occasionally for each of the different epoch sizes - sometimes the crash is during the first 10 epochs, sometimes during the last 10 epochs and other times somewhere in the middle.

```
Macbook Pro M2 Max (2023) Sonoma 14.1.1
Python 3.11.7
tensorflow 2.15.0
```

I am certain, and have verified that the data is consistent (never empty) and does not have different shapes. I am loading the training the data from a file, so I don't understand why it sometimes crashes with this error of "Incompatible shapes".

I have also made sure that I am not running any other processes during the trainings - and other things to ensure the environment is as consistent as possible each time.